# Ignoring to show a number using sprintf

Tags: c, embedded, printf, c-strings

I have a question about C function sprintf. Is it possible, to show the hex number only if some
condition is OK? Or to print some blank spaces instead?

The DLC is data length, f.e. if I have DLC = 2,
I want to pack only 2 data bytes to buffer, and other 6 bytes need to be ignored or replaced by blank spaces.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%02X  %02X  %02X  %02X  %02X  %02X  %02X  %02X",
    (frame.frameDLC > 0)? frame.frameData[0]:"  ", (frame.frameDLC > 1) ? frame.frameData[1] : "  ",
    (frame.frameDLC > 2) ? frame.frameData[2] : "  ", (frame.frameDLC > 3) ? frame.frameData[3] : "  ", 
    (frame.frameDLC > 4) ? frame.frameData[4] : "  ", (frame.frameDLC > 5) ? frame.frameData[5] : "  ", 
    (frame.frameDLC > 6) ? frame.frameData[6] : "  ", (frame.frameDLC > 7) ? frame.frameData[7] : "  ",
    );
```

Comment: So why not `if (frame.frameDLC > 0) { sprintf(....) } else { strcat(.., "  ") }`?

Comment: That is not a question about `sprintf()` - it is unreasonlable to expect a general purpose stahndard library finction to have such application specific niche behaviour.  You have to code it (as you have done)  albeit somewhat inefficiently.  Better to ask how to achieve your requirement that to ask if `sprintf()` can somehow do it.  That makes it an X-Y problem.

Comment: Is the single space between the 5th and 6th intentional? The inconsistency if intentional makes a solution a little more complex. Do you really need spaces; or could the string simply be null terminated after the last value? That would the solution _much_ simpler.

Comment: You shouldn't use sprintf at all in embedded systems, because it's too slow. Converting from binary to a hex string is trivial without using any library function.

Comment: This one additional space is my mistake, Im sorry

Answer (score 1):

For an embedded system, you really want to avoid bloat library functions like `sprintf` because it takes up lots of execution time and memory. It's a completely unacceptable function to use in a professional setting. Similarly, on mid- to high range systems you'll want to avoid a lot of branches like your `?:` example.

Doing this conversion by hand is quite trivial and some 10 to 100 times faster than sprintf, depending on system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t data[8];
  uint8_t dlc;
} frame_t;

static inline char hex_nibble (uint8_t bin)
{
  return "0123456789ABCDEF"[bin];
}

int main (void)
{
  char buf [100];
  size_t length=0;

  frame_t frame = { .data={0xAA,0xBB,0x55,0x77}, .dlc=4 };
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<frame.dlc; i++)
  {
    buf[length++] = hex_nibble(frame.data[i]>>4&0xF);
    buf[length++] = hex_nibble(frame.data[i]&0xF);
  }
  buf[length]='\0';
  puts(buf);
}
```

If you want to add spaces after the number simply do a second loop:

```
for(uint8_t i=frame.dlc; i<8; i++) 
{ 
  buf[length++] = ' '; 
  buf[length++] = ' '; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responce, it looks very proffesional. However i don't understand this bitwise operations, like why there is >>4&0xF and &0xF. Sorry if it's too trivial question, Im in embedded like 4 months.

Comment: @yeuop The look-up table works on nibbles so you need to mask out one nibble at a time from the byte of data. The first line shifts down the most significant 4 bits then mask. The other masks out the 4 least significant. It's a bit sloppily written, the MISRA compliant version would be `(frame.data[i]>>4) & 0xFu` and `frame.data[i] & 0xFu`. Won't make a difference in this case but might do in other cases.

Comment: Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `sprintf`. Use bounds-checking `snprintf` instead.

> Is it possible, to show the hex number only if some condition is OK? Or to print some blank spaces instead?

Yes, use an `if`. Basically your code is a for loop...

```
char buffer[200];
size_t pos = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < frame.frameDLC; ++i) {
   pos += snprintf(&buffer[pos], sizeof(buffer) - pos, "%02X", frame.frameData[i]);
}
for (size_t i = frame.frameDLC; i < 8; ++i) {
   pos += snprintf(&buffer[pos], sizeof(buffer) - pos, "  ");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this approach is not fool proof: `snprintf()` returns the number of bytes produced by the conversions, not the number of bytes written to the output array, limited by the size argument. Hence `pos` may become larger than `sizeof(buffer)` and `sizeof(buffer) - pos` would produce a very large number, causing `snprintf()` to write to `&buffer[pos]`, beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`sprint()` returns the number of characters output.  You can use this to maintain a "cursor position" in the buffer to output each element incrementally.

```
int bi = 0 ;
for( int di = 0; di < frame.frameDLC; di++ )
{
    bi += sprintf( &buffer[bi], "%02X", frame.frameData[di] ) ;
    if( di + 1 < frame.frameDLC)
    {
        bi += sprintf( &buffer[bi], "  ", frame.frameData[di] ) ;
    }
}
```

The above assumes that there are two spaces between each element and that you do not want/need trailing spaces.

If you are not concerned about trailing spaces it can be simplified to:

```
int bi = 0 ;
for( int di = 0; di < frame.frameDLC; di++ )
{
    bi += sprintf( &buffer[bi], "%02X  ", frame.frameData[di] ) ;
}
```

If the single space between the 5th and 6th in your question is deliberate, then you need perhaps:

```
if( di + 1 < frame.frameDLC)
{
    bi += sprintf( &buffer[bi], 
                   di == 4 ? " " :"  ", 
                   frame.frameData[di] ) ;
}
```

And if you truly need to space-pad the string to 29 characters (as the code in your question does), then a second loop starting from `bi` to add trailing spaces will be required.